# How to include logging in a Perl module?

Tags: perl, logging

I'd like to include logging in a Perl module I am writing, but maintain portability so that applications that use it are not bound to a specific logging mechanism, such as [Log::Log4Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.33/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm).

I've considered;

1. Logging to STDERR and leaving it to the application to redirect these messages to it's own logging mechanism (as mentioned in the [Log::Log4Perl FAQ](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/FAQ.html#e95ee)).
2. Including no logging in the module at all.

I suspect there is a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Log::Any](http://p3rl.org/Log::Any)

> Log::Any allows CPAN modules to safely and efficiently log messages, while letting the application choose (or decline to choose) a logging mechanism such as Log::Dispatch or Log::Log4perl.

Comment: That looks really interesting. I can't find much discussion about it, some I'm curious if anyone is using it?

Comment: A reverse dependency search shows some usage: https://metacpan.org/requires/distribution/Log-Any?sort=[[2,1]] .  I'm going to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever way you end up doing, you're going to have to pick one, and that's going to tie it to a mechanism. So may as well pick one.

Why not check if Log::Log4Perl is available? If it is, great, use it. If not, either implement a callback that your users can hook into, or a minimal set of API to let them control what (or if) you log at all?